# Datatables lengthMenu backdrop not covering whole page

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using datatables 1.10.25, but i'm having an issue that i've never seen before.

When I click on the 'Page Lenght' menu, a backdrop shows up, but it is only covering the div it is in, instead of covering the whole page.

this is the code I'm using:

```
$('#tbl-workspaces').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    fixedHeader: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    bPaginate: false,
    order: [[1, "asc"]],
    buttons: [
        'pageLength',
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [1, 2, 3]
            }
        }
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        { orderable: false, targets: [0, 4] }
    ]
});
```

How can I make the backdrop cover the whole page?